# Unable to export test cases in latest Selenium-IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

The latest `Selenium-IDE` seems doesn't have the export feature to dump tests in the desired language; say, `Ruby, Java, Python`.

Is there any option to enable it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is not in scope for now; To know the status, stay-tuned with https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium-ide/issues/131

Comment: Yes, it does; however the Selenium-IDE is from official SeleniumHQ; so, it should be better soon :)